# Difference between Keyword driven framework and hybrid framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

What are key differences between keyword driven and hybrid automation framework??

What is robot framework used in automation?

Is this feasible for web application??

Comment: http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial-34.html

http://robotframework.org/

Comment: Can robot framework be used in selenium apart from QTP?

Comment: Why you want to use robot framework in Selenium, What is your requirement. In Robot there is wrapper library which support maximum Selenium keyword

Comment: Hi Akash.. Can you please share some documentation on robot framework I'm new to this i dont know completely where exactly to use it

Comment: @user7541973: _"can robot framework be used in selenium apart from QTP?"_ - robot framework can be used _with_ selenium, and it definitely can be run without qtp. All the documentation you need is at http://www.robotframework.org

Comment: How do you define "hybrid automation framework" That phrase doesn't make much sense out of context.